# Get the anniversary of the users using graph api

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

From the Distribution list of users need to get the list users who are going to complete their work anniversary in the next month using filter. Able to get the users employee hire date need a filter for the Employee hire date property based on the month so that instead of pulling all the users specific group of users i can fetch

Comment: Could provide more details? You want to filter users with 1 year work anniversary in the next month?

Comment: yes want the users who are going to complete one year ,5 years, 10 years(multiple of 5 years ) in the next month and tried with graph query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group id]/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=employeehiredate,displayName&$filter=EmployeeHireDate/Month eq 10 and tried with filter $filter=Month(EmployeeHireDate) eq 10 getting the error invalid filter clause

Comment: Understand. Unfortunately, Graph API doesn't support filtering datetimeoffset by only year, month or a day. Also month() function is not supported by Graph API

Comment: So we need to fetc all the members of the DList and loop through that is the only option we are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't filter `employeeHireDate` by year, month or a day.

You need to send several requests to get all data you need. For filtering by `employeeHireDate` you need to add header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` and query parameter `$count=true`

Get users with one year anniversary in the next month

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,employeeHireDate&$filter=employeeHireDate ge 2021-12-01T00:00:01Z and employeeHireDate le 2021-12-31T23:59:59Z&$count=true
```

Similar for users with 5, 10, etc. years anniversary

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,employeeHireDate&$filter=employeeHireDate ge 2017-12-01T00:00:01Z and employeeHireDate le 2017-12-31T23:59:59Z&$count=true

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,employeeHireDate&$filter=employeeHireDate ge 2012-12-01T00:00:01Z and employeeHireDate le 2012-12-31T23:59:59Z&$count=true
```